# Swift objc_getAssociatedObject always nil

Tags: swift, associated-object

I am trying to associated a property to an Array Extension:

```
private var AssociatedObjectHandle: String = "BlaBLabla"
extension Array {
  var emptyIndex:Int {
    mutating get {
      if let object = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectHandle) {
        return object as! Int
      }
      let index = self.searchEmptyIndex()
      self.emptyIndex = index

      return index
    }
    set {
      let new = (newValue as NSInteger)
      objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectHandle, new, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }
  }

  func searchEmptyIndex() -> Int {
      if let arr = self as? [Int] {
        return arr.index(of: -1)!
      }

      return -1
  }
}
```

The objc_getAssociatedObject call always returns nil!!

Anyone has any idea why?

I am banging my head for the last hour about this...

Comment: is `searchEmptyIndex` API your code too?  Could you include that in your question?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that... Added

Comment: I'm assuming `searchEmptyIndex` lives within your Array extension, right?  In your code up there it's outside the extension.

Comment: Correct.. 
Updated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You *cannot* add associated objects to a Swift `Array` (or any Swift value type). 
`objc_setAssociatedObject()` and `objc_getAssociatedObject()` are from the
Objective-C runtime, they expect an instance of `NSObject` as first
argument.

Your code compiles and runs only because any Swift value is automatically
bridged  to an object if necessary.

- When you call `objc_setAssociatedObject(self, ...)` then `self`
  is bridged to a (temporary) instance of `NSArray`, and the association
  is made on that object.
- Later, when `objc_getAssociatedObject(self, ...)` is called,
  *another* (temporary) instance of `NSArray` is created, and that
  has no associated object.

That's why you get `nil` as the result.

Comment: So how can I add properties on Swift type extensions?

Comment: @YanivH: You can't.

Comment: And you cannot subclass an Array as well in Swift?

Comment: @YanivH: No, `struct Array` is a value type, not a class.